Downloaded font is not being rendered correctly on the browser
I am having issues with fonts I downloaded that are not being rendered on the browser.
I define the font face in the index.css file, which is the root css file.
@font-face {
  font-family: "RecoletaAlt";
  src: local("RecoletaAlt") url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff")
    format("woff") url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

I have the font loaded into the index.html page too
<link
  rel="prefetch"
  href="./src/assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff"
/>
<link
  rel="prefetch"
  href="./src/assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff2"
  as="font"
  type="font/woff2"
/>

Then I try using the font here as shown. When I inspect it in the browser, it shows that the font-family is RecoletaAlt but when I check the computer tab, I see, "Family name: Times
PostScript name: Times-Bold, Font origin: Local file(11 glyphs)" which shows that it is not using the font. Also when the page loads, and I check the network tab I see the font in the network request which shows that it is being loaded.
<h2
   className="text-3xl font-semibold text-center mb-6"
   style={{
      fontFamily: "RecoletaAlt",
      fontSize: "30px",
      fontWeight: "700",
   }}
 >Get started</h2>

Below is my file structure


there are several problems in your approach but an answer would go too far.. so to begin with: you are using 2 distinct strategies for the same task... you should use OR <link> OR @font-face; your @font-face definition is wrong.. look here for the correct syntax; the relative urls should be relative to the resource so I think that in the #font-face should be ../assets/[...] and in the <link> should be ./assets/[...] (or just use urls starting with /)

@DiegoD Thank you so much for this. I simply just copied the syntax there and relaced the values with mine and it worked. I still don't know what the difference between that and mine was. Note: I changed the url to the previous and it worked fine.

@oyerohabib: different sources need to be seperated by commas. You missed these so the font urls can't be retrieved. BTW better remove the local() value and start with the woff2 src: url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff2") format("woff2"), url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff") format("woff");

@herrstrietzel Ohh, thank you, my eyes somehow skipped that.

I was able to resolve the issue from the comments made. I realized I omitted the comma between the different font formats.
Before (Not working)
@font-face {
  font-family: "RecoletaAlt";
  src: local("RecoletaAlt") url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff")
    format("woff") url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

After (works fine)
@font-face {
  font-family: "RecoletaAlt";
  src: local("RecoletaAlt"), url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff")
    format("woff"), url("./assets/fonts/RecoletaAlt.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

I hope it helps someone.
